# How does pip know what to uninstall?

Tags: python, pip

Say you installed a package `foo`.
Now you’re uninstalling `foo` with pip.

What exactly does `pip uninstall foo` do?
How does it know to do that?

Does it just delete the `foo` folder and its eggs from the Python packages directory? (+ any relevant dependencies)

Or does `pip uninstall` sometimes do more than that?
Maybe package authors provide a uninstall.py file maybe.

---

I understand that if I want to make sure I uninstall a Python package, I can run:

```
python setup.py install --record files.txt
```

while installing the package, then remove all the files in `files.txt`.

Is that essentially what pip does: track what files were created during setup and remove them? What more to it is there than that?

Comment: Pip just runs `uninstall` on each of the packages in the file.

Comment: @JammyDodger What does the uninstall command do? How dos it know to do that? That’s what I’m missing.

Comment: Every package in `pip` has a standard name, so it knows which to install/uninstall

Comment: @KostasCharitidis I must have phrased my question quite poorly. I’m not asking how pip knows _which package_ to uninstall, I’m asking when you tell it to uninstall package foo, what does it do, and how does it know to do that? Does it simply delete the foo folder and eggs from the system package directory?

Comment: @YatharthAgarwal yes it removes the package folder from `Lib\site-packages`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that essentially what pip does: track what files were created during setup and remove them?

Yes.

> What more to it is there than that?

If all recorded files were successfully removed `pip uninstall` removes the package directory and the corresponding `.dist-info` directory (where it stored metadata including the list of files in the package).

And that's all. The end of the story.

Comment: Could you provide some proofs on that?

Comment: This looks wrong. For example, I have a package `numpy` installed (`pip show numpy` outputs its information). However, when I run `pip show -f numpy`, it errors: *Required-by: scipy
Files:
Cannot locate RECORD or installed-files.txt*

Comment: @YaroslavNikitenko You have a broken installation. Most probably you couldn't uninstall it if you try. My advice is to reinstall it: `pip install --force-reinstall numpy` or even `pip install --force-reinstall --ignore-installed numpy`

Comment: Maybe you are right (`pacman` shows that numpy was not installed with that). Thanks for the suggestion. Then I'm curious what could break that installation. The details of this "installed files tracking".

Comment: `pacman` (and any other system package manager) knows nothing about packages installed with `pip`. Esp. when these packages have been installed into Python virtual environments (which is the recommended way).

Comment: Yes, my point is that since `pacman` doesn't know about the package, this means it was installed exactly by `pip`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is that essentially what pip does: track what files were created during setup and remove them?

There's one detail here: `pip uninstall x` will uninstall the `x` package, but if it had to install other dependencies before, those will stay, since it doesn't check if the dependencies used by `x` are still used by other packages. They always stay, and that can be a little annoying sometimes.